# OLS Estimator Expressed in Terms of Correlation, Mistake in Textbook?

Tags: correlation, least-squares, estimators

in the textbook "Introductory to Econometrics" Wooldridge writes

$\hat{\beta}_1=\hat{p}_{xy}\cdot(\frac{\hat{\sigma}_x}{\hat{\sigma}_y})$

where $\hat{\beta}_1$ is the OLS-Estimator, $\hat{p}_{xy}$ is the correlation between $x$ and $y$, and $\hat{\sigma}_x$ is the standard deviation of $x$.
When I derive this formula I always come up with

$\hat{\beta}_1=\hat{p}_{xy}\cdot(\frac{\hat{\sigma}_y}{\hat{\sigma}_x})$.

Also according to wikipedia this formula is true. Did Wooldridge accidentally invert the fraction?

Comment: It looks like you got it right. Wooldridge made a mistake at least with that one case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a typo. In simple regression,

$$y = a + bx + u$$

the OLS estimator for $b$ is
$$\hat b = \frac {\hat Cov(x,y)}{\hat \sigma^2_x}$$

Since $\text{Cov}(x,y) = \hat \rho_{x,y}\cdot \hat \sigma_x \cdot \hat \sigma_y$ we get

$$\hat b = \hat \rho_{x,y}\frac {\hat \sigma_y}{\hat \sigma_x}$$